# How to creat an Android and iOS info app that can be edited without development?

Tags: android, ios, xcode, android-studio

So I want to make an information app and I want to be able to update the information in the app without having to develop and release the app constantly. Currently I use xcode and Android studios. So I have a 2 part question;

First what is the best way to update an info app with information without continuous development?

What is the best development studio to create an app for both iOS and Android or is what I am currently using the best way?

Also the information will be images and text.

Look forward to any responses.

Comment: The best development studio is a matter of opinion, so there won't be a "correct" answer....

for updating informatins you need a web service, there are although many approaches and you should first invastigate some time to this topic.

Answer (score 1):

well if you want to want to create a an application for both **iOS** and **Andriod**  my openion is to use [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) or [Flutter](https://flutter.dev) or [Xamarin](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/xamarin) because it will give you a app for both platform with single code and you can develop using single IDE.

and second if you want to update data with static layout then create layout once and for rest of data crate a server based application all you have to do update the server it will automatically update content in the application.